# how to access String... (varargs) to get specific characters and save them into String

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

as it mentioned in the title, I have this code

```
  String a = flett("AM ","L","GEDS","ORATKRR","","R TRTE","IO","TGAUU");

public static String flett(String... s){
    StringBuilder merge = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        merge.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return merge;
}
```

I got an error at chartAt(i) ?
how for example I can call every character in the array s and save them into merge or call an specific character like the first character from each one and save them into merge ?

Comment: @StephenC String is different from String... I can't write s.chartAt(0)

Comment: The idea is that you first try something and then ask a question if you get stuck

Comment: Are you looking for characters in a String variable or an index of a String array?

Comment: @husseinalbirouti String... is an array of Strings, iterate over that, and use charAt(0)

Comment: also: implement error handling. what have you tried so far?

Comment: start with trying to write code that compiles. This code won't, since your method is missing a return statement

Comment: Edited: i have added what I have tried so far

Comment: @deHaar before the edit, it was an array as well. and it won't work. he is using  chartAt instead of charAt, he is running a return statement in the first iteration of his loop, he doesn't have a return statement for each possible scenario ...
I'm not sure what error Hussein is talking about, but if this is his code, it will never compile

Comment: @deHaar this is exactly what I wanted. thanks and please vote for my question if you got what I need when you read it.

Comment: @Stultuske my comment became deprecated after a lot of edits by the OP... I think it's worth getting removed...

Comment: @husseinalbirouti have you read my answer or do you mean my comment? I removed it because it was not completely correct regarding your current version of code in your question. Returning `merge.toString()` should do it for now...

Comment: @deHaar I read your comment and that what I need it. as mentioned in my question. I don't know how to access the array. when I add s[I] to my code, it worked.

Comment: @husseinalbirouti you will find the correct answer in one of the below answers, which are all correct. Just mark one of them as accepted and maybe vote it up, if you like and have enough reputation to do so. Thanks...

Comment: @Stultuske I added what I tried to do so far as other people asked me to. and what I did after just arranged my code.

Comment: yes, but for certain code you posted, you said "I get an error on this". you left it vague whether it was compile time, runtime, .. either way, it looked as if you meant to say that that was the only problem with the code, which it wasn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a variable amount of `String` parameters, then concatenate all first characters of non empty `String`s of the parameters and return the concatenated object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = flett("AM ","L","GEDS","ORATKRR","","R TRTE","IO","TGAUU", "HOLA", "MMMMH");
    System.out.println(s);
}

// Please note the parameter, it takes a various amount of Strings  
public static String flett(String ... values) {
    // create something that concatenates Strings (other options possible)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // the parameters are now an array of Strings, which you can "foreach"
    for (String s : values) {
        // check for empty ones and skip those
        if (!s.equals("")) {
            // append the first character of a valid parameter
            sb.append(s.charAt(0));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Be surprised by the output…

Answer (score 3):

```
s[i].charAt(j);
```

where `i` - the index of an array, `j` - the index of a letter within a `String`.

A Java 8 method that collects the first letter of each array's element might look like

```
public String flett(String... s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s)
                 .map(i -> i.length() > 0 ? String.valueOf(i.charAt(0)) : "")
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

For the array `"AM ","L","GEDS","ORATKRR","","R TRTE","IO","TGAUU"`, it results in `"ALGORIT"`.

Comment: you didn't like my Java 8 approach, did you?

Answer (score 1):

This method get some Strings and Create String from the first character of each String.

```
  public static String flett(String... s) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(s.length);
        for (String a : s) {
            if (!a.isEmpty()) {
                res.append(a.charAt(0));
            }
        }
        return res.toString();
    }
```